# Docker and mysql 8 can't start

Tags: mysql, docker

I need to create an env with mysql so I tried to set it up in this way:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:

  #PHP Service
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: php:latest
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./docker/php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
      - app-network

  #Nginx Service
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
    - VIRTUAL_PORT=80
    - VIRTUAL_HOST=project.local
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./docker/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - app-network

  #MySQL Service
  db:
    #image: mysql:5.7.22
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql/
      - ./docker/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    networks:
      - app-network

#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
#Volumes
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.2.2-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y mysql-client \
 && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    mysql-client \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www

# Change current user to www
USER www

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

nginx/conf.d/app.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/public;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}
```

mysql/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
secure-file-priv = NULL
general_log = 1
general_log_file = /var/lib/mysql/general.log
```

php/local.ini

```
upload_max_filesize=40M
post_max_size=40M
```

When I run `docker-compose up` the `db` keep rebooting with this output:

```
db           | 2019-07-18T16:12:55.125391Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.16) starting as process 1
db           | 2019-07-18T16:12:55.134118Z 1 [System] [MY-011012] [Server] Starting upgrade of data directory.
db           | 2019-07-18T16:12:55.219171Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012526] [InnoDB] Upgrade after a crash is not supported. This redo log was created with MySQL 5.7.22. Please follow the instructions at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading.html
db           | 2019-07-18T16:12:55.219205Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
db           | 2019-07-18T16:12:55.828854Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011013] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine.
db           | 2019-07-18T16:12:55.829512Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
db           | 2019-07-18T16:12:55.829780Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
db           | 2019-07-18T16:12:55.834884Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.16)  MySQL Community Server
```

How can I use mysql 8?

PS:
I used the same configuration with mysql5.7 before comment it out and add mysql8

Comment: _"Upgrade after a crash is not supported. This redo log was created with MySQL 5.7.22. Please follow the instructions at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading.html"_ I can say sufficiently self explanatory no?

Comment: you can't just switch the mysql version. You have to **upgrade** it. It is not working as php

Comment: major changes happened on later mysql5 versions and up. try downgrading to 5.7

Comment: And if I want to start over with just mysql8?